# Is there a way we restrict editing of fields in contract once activated

Tags: administration

I want to make sure that noone can edit the contract records once its activated. I also have a custom object contract line items and these records also should not be allowed to be deleted.

I want to avoid the use of triggers to the max as possible

Comment: and what have you tried?  there are many possible good answers here

Comment: I know the use of triggers which i really want to avoid. What really are the options available? i am not looking for actual implementations but pointers would be just enough

Comment: Another option i can think of is to change the recordtype of the record and have a pageLayout associated with the  recordtype to have the fields as read only

Answer (score 0):

From the [Object Reference on Contract](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contract.htm):

> Client applications must initially create a Contract in a non-Activated state. Client applications can subsequently activate a Contract by updating it and setting the value in its Status field to Activated; however, the Status field is the only field you can update when activating the Contract.
>
> Once a Contract has been activated, your client application can't change its status; however, prior to activation, your client application can change the status value from Draft to InApproval via the API. Also, your client application can delete contracts whose status is Draft or InApproval but not when a contract status is Activated.

Once activated, a contract can't be updated. However, client applications can use the API to create, update, delete, and query any Attachment associated with a contract. Unless your `Contract Line Item` is in a M-D relationship with Contract, you'll probably want to use FLS settings on it, along with workflow/approvals to change it to read-only once the status is set to `activated`.

Comment: How do you change FLS using workflow?

Comment: Or are referring to change the recordtype of the record so that the pagelayout has all the fields readonly

Comment: Yes, this is an out of the box "feature" for Contracts. It happens as part of the approval process. Apparently the Type changes and "locks" the file in some manner. I understand it as going beyond a RecordType change, but am not certain of the details. It happens at the API level and is not a page layout level change. Again, take a look at the Object Reference for more.